# Logging parallel threads in logback

Tags: multithreading, webdriver, testng, logback

I'll try to make a brief description of my Selenium framework so that I can explain my problem.

I use **Selenium 2** (current version 2.3.1) + **testNG 5.14**

I set testng.xml file to run the tests in the test suite in parallel, just 2 instances

For logging purposes, I use **logback** (I've read is the next best thing in the log world)

My problem is that when checking what the application logs I get something like this:

> 18:48:58.551 [TestNG] INFO  d.a.a.s.t.setup.TestConfiguration -
>   Retrieving random User from User Pool
>
> 18:48:58.551 [TestNG] INFO  d.a.a.s.t.setup.TestConfiguration -
>   Retrieving random User from User Pool
>
> 18:48:58.551 [TestNG] DEBUG d.a.a.s.t.setup.TestConfiguration -
>   Creating DataSource for acccessing DataBase
>
> 18:48:58.551 [TestNG] DEBUG d.a.a.s.t.setup.TestConfiguration -
>   Creating DataSource for acccessing DataBase
>
> 18:48:58.552 [TestNG] DEBUG d.a.a.s.t.setup.TestConfiguration -
>   Launching SQL Query
>
> 18:48:58.552 [TestNG] DEBUG d.a.a.s.t.setup.TestConfiguration -
>   Launching SQL Query
>
> 18:48:59.613 [TestNG] TRACE d.a.a.s.t.setup.TestConfiguration - Query
>   succesful
>
> 18:48:59.613 [TestNG] TRACE d.a.a.s.t.setup.TestConfiguration - Query
>   succesful

As you may see, it is impossible to see the difference between the two threads that are running at the same time. My question is, is there a way I can configure the logback settings so that they also add a number or Id to identify each thread that is running?

PD Just in case it may help, my **logback.xml** file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/selenium.log</file>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Logback [Mapped Diagnostic Context](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) (MDC) is your friend.  It allows you to add thread local variables that can be managed, copied between threads, and logged using a logging format.

From the docs:

> One of the design goals of logback is to audit and debug complex distributed applications. Most real-world distributed systems need to deal with multiple clients simultaneously. In a typical multithreaded implementation of such a system, different threads will handle different clients. A possible but slightly discouraged approach to differentiate the logging output of one client from another consists of instantiating a new and separate logger for each client. This technique promotes the proliferation of loggers and may increase their management overhead.
>
> A lighter technique consists of uniquely stamping each log request servicing a given client. Neil Harrison described this method in the book Patterns for Logging Diagnostic Messages in Pattern Languages of Program Design 3, edited by R. Martin, D. Riehle, and F. Buschmann (Addison-Wesley, 1997). Logback leverages a variant of this technique included in the SLF4J API: Mapped Diagnostic Contexts (MDC).
>
> To uniquely stamp each request, the user puts contextual information into the MDC, the abbreviation of Mapped Diagnostic Context. The salient parts of the MDC class are shown below. Please refer to the [MDC javadocs](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html) for a complete list of methods.

Comment: Thanks, Ceki! MDC worked perfectly fine for me. If anybody is interested, I've created a Listener class (subclass of **TestListenerAdapter**) and on method onStart(ITestContext testContext) I put this line: **MDC.put("tests", testContext.getName());**

Answer (score 8):

If you would like an alternative to the unpredictable names you get with %thread as I usually do, you can use simple thread-local IDs. Its much easier on the eyes. This will work with logback...

```
public class ThreadIdConverter extends ClassicConverter {
  private static int nextId = 0;
  private static final ThreadLocal<String> threadId = new ThreadLocal<String>() {    
    @Override
    protected String initialValue() {
      int nextId = nextId();
      return String.format("%05d", nextId);
    }
  };

  private static synchronized int nextId() {
    return ++nextId;
  }

  @Override
  public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
    return threadId.get();
  }
}
```

Then put this simple line in your logback XML:

```
<conversionRule conversionWord="tid" 
    converterClass="com.yourstuff.logback.ThreadIdConverter" />
```

Set your pattern something like this (notice "tid"):

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%tid] %-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
```

And your logs will look like this:

```
10:32:02.517 [00001] INFO something here
10:32:02.517 [00002] INFO something here
10:32:02.517 [00003] INFO something here
10:32:02.517 [00001] INFO something more here 
10:32:02.517 [00001] INFO something more here
```

You can do this with any logger that supports custom extensions. Hope it helps.

Comment: You could use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of bothering with synchronization on your nextId method.

Comment: Thanks Jerico. I used your class until switching over to `AsyncAppender`s, which prevents your `ThreadIdConverter` from functioning properly, because `threadId.get()` will be run on a different thread. Here's my alternative. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62765739/709537

Answer (score 6):

FYI, you can output the thread id using %thread as described in the documentation at http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html :

```
The output is formatted using a PatternLayoutEncoder set to the pattern %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want thread ids, rather than thread names, and are using an asynchronous appender, Jerico Sandhorn's ThreadIdConverter will not work as expected, because it gets run on a different thread. In that case you can drop in this class.

```java
public class ThreadIdConverter extends ClassicConverter {
    private static final AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger();
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> name2Id = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private static String getNextThreadId(String name) {
        return String.format("%05d", nextId.getAndIncrement());
    }

    @Override
    public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
        return name2Id.computeIfAbsent(event.getThreadName(), ThreadIdConverter::getNextThreadId);
    }
}
```

Configuration works the same way:

```xml
    <conversionRule conversionWord="tid" converterClass="pkg.ThreadIdConverter" />
    ....
    <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS},%tid,,%msg%n</pattern>
```

N.B. This class works with `AsyncAppender`, because the thread name is retrieved before going asynchronous. Also note that if threads have the same name, they will get the same id. However, this is not going to happen in practice, unless you set the same name to multiple threads on purpose, which is generally not a wise thing to do.