# how to add new log value to all logging statements

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I am using slf4j with logback in my project.there is one request_id  stored in a ThreadLoacal.
I want to add the value of this request id to all log statements.
Is there any way so that logger implicitly pick up the value of request_id and  log it as well, without being pass it in existing log statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slf4j and logback both supports the usage of a mapped diagnostic context (MDC). You can add named values to the MDC, which are passed to the logger. The logging pattern supports tokens for output.

Note that the MDC is stuck to your thread, i.e. with a different thread the context is lost. And with thread reusage, the context will reappear, so cleaning is important in such situations.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have to add the information in an extra place.  The custom Converter approach should render thread locals that already exist and were (presumably) created for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using a custom Converter.

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19119154/139985) to another question shows how you can use a Converter to incorporate a thread identifier that has been saves in a thread-local variable.  You should be able to adapt this to incorporate a request id.

[This section of the logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#customConversionSpecifier) describes how to hook a custom converter into your logback configs.

Answer (score 0):

This can be tedious, But, I am sure it would do it

1. Firstly [configure sl4j logging](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-configure-slf4j-with-different.html) with the JDK logger.
2. Write your own formatter, or override the Java [SimpleFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/logging/Logger.html) like so:

   ```
   package com.mypackage
   public class MyFormatter extends SimpleFormatter{

       @Override
       public String format(LogRecord record){
           String simpleFormattedLog = super.format(record);
           String simpleFormattedLogWithThreadID = "THREAD_ID(" + getThreadId() + ") _ " + simpleFormattedLog; 
          return  simpleFormattedLogWithThreadID;
       }



       private String getThreadId(){
           return  "GET THREAD ID HERE";
       }

   }
   ```

   Then [specify the formatter in the properties file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19717-01/819-7753/gcblo/index.html) as

   ```
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = com.mypackage.MyFormatter
   ```

This should work, all things being equal.

Comment: OP is using logback. Why are you suggesting he should switch over to JDK logger? Logback provides stronger facilities for this kind of need.

Comment: True, I am sorry for giving an achaic way, just a solution I know, would read on Logback. Thanks